# discord.py Bot is Not Starting

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an entry point module like this. It's fine and it works.

```py
"""Entry Point"""

import os
import asyncio
from app.core import BotClient # subclass of `discord.ext.commands.Bot`

async def main():
    try:
        bot = BotClient()
        await bot.start(os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        await bot.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

But when I put the `bot` variable in the `if __name__ == "__main__":`, the bot won't start anymore. The program is still running and blocked but the `Bot.on_ready` function is not firing.

```py
"""Entry Point"""

import os
import asyncio
from app.core import BotClient # subclass of `discord.ext.commands.Bot`

async def main():
    try:
        await bot.start(os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        await bot.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        bot = BotClient()
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: How are you running the module?

Comment: By running it directly like `python3.9 run.py`.